# Circle CI: error cloning repository: repository not found

Tags: github, circleci

While trying to build a project in CircleCI I got the below error:

> Either git or ssh (required by git to clone through SSH) is not installed in the image. Falling back to CircleCI's native git client but the behavior may be different from official git. If this is an issue, please use an image that has official git and ssh installed.
> Cloning git repository

> error cloning repository: repository not found

And this causes the build to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was that the engineer who set up the project set a **Deploy Key** and **User Key** specific to him left the company, so his access to the company GitHub repo projects was revoked, which made the existing **Deploy Key** and **User Key** for the project in Circle CI obsolete.

All I had to do was to:

- Go to **Project Settings**
- Then **SSH Keys**
- Remove the existing **Deploy Key** and **User Key** (if any)
- Add a new **Deploy Key**
- (Optional - Not needed) Add a new User key (by authorizing with GitHub)

[image]

After this, I was able to build the project successfully in Circle CI

Comment: This scared us a ton when it happened! This was the exact reason. Thanks for posting!